# UIslider control as iTunes

Tags: ios, itunes, uislider, audio-player

created a music player and my tracking progress is uislider with thumb as iTunes . everything seems good except the touch of the slider thumb is not smoothly as iTunes. in iTunes music player the thumb is get touch easily although the dash (thumb image) is too small.

[image]

how can I do like iTunes ? can I wide the thumb touch space. I added transparent area in thumb hight but nothing change.

I want the dragging be smoothly , now it needs to tap the thumb and then dragging. plz , I lost a long time try to improve it as iTunes

this is my code for creation the slider

```
   progressView = [[UISlider  alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 30, 200, 7)];
    [progressView addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderMoved:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
 [progressView setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumb.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 progressView.continuous=YES;
 [self.view addSubview:progressView];



- (IBAction)sliderMoved:(UISlider *)aSlider{
 if (streamer.duration)
    {

        double newSeekTime = (aSlider.value) * streamer.duration;
    [streamer seekToTime:newSeekTime];

    }
```

}

Comment: What iTunes player are you talking about, do you mean the iOS music player or the iTunes app? Can you also post some code how you implemented the slider?

Comment: Yes I mean iOS music player

Comment: Post your code, without it we can not help you.

Comment: @rckoenes I edited my question with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this article provide the solution by increasing the thumb clickable area

http://mpatric.blogspot.com/2009/04/more-responsive-sliders-on-iphone.html